# What is the best package for game developing in Java?

Tags: java

What is the best package for game developing in Java; I work with JITTers but it's too weak for example how can I make a game such as [Splinter Cell Conviction](http://splintercell.us.ubi.com)? :)

What is the best in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223478/coming-back-to-java-after-a-long-absence-good-java-game-dev-resources Also see related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392/game-programming-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899155/how-to-learn-game-development

Comment: Thanks Dear The Feast it was useful rep++ ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JMonkey Engine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com) is quite good.  It's a scenegraph engine which is layered on top of LWJGL or JOGL.  It's quite nice.  A couple of years ago, we were using Irrlicht with Java.  We switched over to JMonkey Engine, and found it to be much easier to do what we needed.

Comment: @Mike: jME is completely open source under the BSD license.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at [jirr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jirr/), the Java binding to Irrlicht. It's a bit outdated (latest Irrlicht version is 1.7, jirr only up to 1.4.x). It contains mostly 3D stuff, so it's *not* a full game engine library.

There's also [LWJGL (Lightweight Java Game Library)](http://lwjgl.org/), but I've never used that.

Comment: All three libraries AndiDog mentioned are opensource and therefore free.  You can even use them in a commercial setting.